# Returning Moq instance from another mock

Tags: c#, rest, dependency-injection, mocking, restsharp

I am writing some unit tests (of which I am only just new to) and want to be able to create a mocking of RestSharp to build various HTTP requests.

At the moment I am using three interfaces based on Restsharp; `IRestClient`, `IRestRequest` and `IRestResponse`

The premise of mocking as I understand it is to return predictable results through falsification, and I am having trouble with constructing a mock for this through Moq and Ninject.

As it stands, I have the following retrievals from the kernel;

```
//Create RESTful interface ecosystem (RestRequest => RestClient => RestResponse)
var clientMock = _kernel.GetMock<IRestClient>();
var requestMock = _kernel.GetMock<IRestRequest>();
var responseMock = _kernel.GetMock<IRestResponse>();
```

I essentially need to return the `responseMock` whenever I execute the `clientMock.Execute(IRestRequest)` method.

Is this the right way to be doing things, as I am unable to mock a return of responseMock from this code;

```
clientMock.Setup(f => f.Execute(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>())).Returns(responseMock);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mock<T>` lets you define the behavior of the mock but doesn't represent the actual mocked instance. Because you want to return an object of type `IRestResponse`, not `Mock<IRestResponse>`, use the `Mock<T>.Object` property to get an instance of type `T`:

```
clientMock
    .Setup(f => f.Execute(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
    .Returns(responseMock.Object);
```

Comment: This works, however, for whatever reason, I was using the `Returns()` method with a generics tag (i.e: `Returns<T>()`. I have removed this from the question, and suggested an edit on your response.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in my instance
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244204/return-a-mock-from-a-mocked-method