# Return a Mock from a Mocked method

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I'm not sure how I would do this.

Given I have

```
public interface IFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    IWrapper<T> GetT(string s);
}

public interface IWrapper<out T> where T : new()
{
    void Execute(Action<T> action);
}
```

When I do this

```
public class MoqTest
{
    public void test()
    {
        Mock<IWrapper<basicClass>> wrapperMock = new Mock<IWrapper<basicClass>>();
        Mock<IFactory<basicClass>> factoryMock = new Mock<IFactory<basicClass>>()
            .Setup(p => p.GetT(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(wrapperMock.Object);
    }
}
```

I get this

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `Moq.Language.Flow.IReturnsResult<TestNamespace.IFactory<TestNamespace.basicClass>>`
>   to `Moq.Mock<TestNamespace.IFactory<TestNamespace.basicClass>>`. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Note that these are just mocked example objects.

It seems it doesn't consider the return type equivalent. One being a `IReturnResult`, the other a `Moq.Mock`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem basically is that you are assigning the result of invoking the `Returns` method to the `factoryMock` variable.

You want to first create the mock and assign it to the `factoryMock` variable and then set the mock up like this:

```
Mock<IWrapper<basicClass>> wrapperMock = new Mock<IWrapper<basicClass>>();
Mock<IFactory<basicClass>> factoryMock = new Mock<IFactory<basicClass>>();

factoryMock
    .Setup(p => p.GetT(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(wrapperMock.Object);
```

Comment: Looking back at this two months later, this is quite obvious.